# Does "Spare Grain" give you food without you doing anything?

Tags: king-of-dragon-pass

The Issaries blessing "Spare Grain" is listed as "Obtains extra food via trade." On first read, I thought this meant bonus food only when buying food via caravans.

Does "Spare Grain" give you food automatically or does it require using caravans?

Answer (score 3):

The Spare Grain blessing is useful even with no trading partners. And I can’t think of a blessing that requires you to do something in particular, so you don’t need to send caravans.

Answer (score 1):

Spare grain blessing give you more food. 
It's more effective if you have more trading partners.

So yes it requires from you to use trades.